# Will modifications to a function's return value in the finally block take effect?

Tags: java, exception

Consider the following code:

```
 int dummy() {     
     int x = 0; 
     try { 
        x = x + 1; 
        throw new Exception(); 
     } catch (Exception e) { 
       x = x + 2; 
       return x; 
     } finally {
      x = x + 4;  
 }
```

I need to "predict" the behaviour of this method without programming it. My question is, what will the return value be?

My guess would be that when an exception occurs, the `finally` block will be realized, so the value of `x` will be 4. But I think the value will not be returned. And if no exception occurs, the value will be 2 and it will be returned.

I'm a complete beginner (less than 3 months) in programming so I might be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following things will happen when you will call this method:

1. The expression, `x = x + 1;` will increase the value of `x` by `1` i.e. its value will become `1`. Then, `throw new Exception();` will be executed and as a result, the control will enter the `catch` block.
2. Inside the `catch` block, `x = x + 2;` will increase the value of `x` by `2` i.e. its value will become `3` which is the value that will be returned.
3. Since `finally` block is supposed to be executed irrespective of whether an exception is thrown or not, this block will be executed but it won't change the return value. Thus, `finally` block is useless here. Typically, `finally` block is used to release resources. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html) to learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `int x` is declared at `0`.

You enter the `try` block and `x` becomes `1`.

An `Exception` is thrown, hence the control moves to the `catch` block.

Here, `x` gets 2 more and goes to `3`, then the value `3` is ready to be returned.

However, the execution continues to execute the `finally` block and `x = x + 4` -> `7` but this doesn't change your return value since when you return an int you're passing its value, not the reference of the variable `x`.

If you want to know more, I'm sure who assigned you this puzzle will be glad to help!